# gcc: fatal error: no input files

Tags: c, git-bash

I wrote this simple line of code and saved it in a file called 'ex.c'.
The code is the following (first line is purposely written wrong as it showed up different in the post):

```
"#include < stdio.h >

int lst[] = {6,3,7,9};

int main(){

  printf("Hello\n");

  return 0;

}
```

I then wanted to compile it using the command `gcc ex.c` but I get an error saying "gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated."

What am I doing wrong?
I use git bash and have installed both msys64 and MinGW to the C directory, aswell as add the gcc in my path enviorment.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

you should add the output executable name

`gcc ex.c -o output` and then you can execute your `output` file with `/output`.

all the other options are available in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. `-o` option just names the output file, if left out, the output will just be always `a.out`.

Comment: Sadly it does not work, still get the same error message

Comment: Could there be some other problem? If I run MSYS2 and write "gcc ex.c" it gives me a different error message than the one in Git Bash.

Comment: I get the following in MSYS2: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.1.0/../../../../lib/libmsys-2.0.a(libcmain.o): In the function ”main”:
/msys_scripts/msys2-runtime/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to ”WinMain”
/msys_scripts/msys2-runtime/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37:(.text.startup+0x82): relocalization truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol ”WinMain”
collect2: fel: ld returned exitstatus 1

Comment: ops, my mistake. silly question, but are you in the right directory?

Comment: Yes if I write "ls" I can see my file ex.c

Comment: can you try to compile it writing the full path to ex.c and put the output here? like gcc c:\path\ex.c

Comment: Hmm, it seems that no matter what I write it gives me the same error, could there be something with how my path variable is set? Under systemvariables I have the following directory in my Path C:\msys64\usr\bin which is where the gcc program is.

Comment: I think that installing [gcc to git bash](https://yichaoou.github.io/tutorials/software/2016/06/28/git-bash-install-gcc) is a different than installing it to MSYS2. did you installed through git bash?

Comment: No I did not, it was through MSYS2, will do it and return with the results! :)

Comment: so, did it work?

Comment: sadly not... I do have other helpful resources since I'm doing this for a course in university (I'm just to eager to wait until the next time I'll be able to), hopefully they can help me.

Comment: @GiovanaMorais now it's working, thank you for your time and help, best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had followed the instructions on the following page: https://github.com/is1200-example-projects/mcb32tools/releases/
But I had forgot the last step which is to download the .run file for msys, I did this and now it is working for MSYS2, Git Bash still not working, but one working is all I need!

STEPS I FORGOT (as taken from the link):

- Download the .run-file for windows. Make sure you download the correct version.
  The x86_64 version is for 64 bit MSYS2 installation and the i686 version for a 32 bit MSYS2 installation.
- Run the .run-file inside the MSYS2 environment (cd to containing directory, run with ./mcb32tools-*.run)"